# Are "what does this mean: [phrase in particular dialect]?" questions off-topc?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/294271/what-does-with-the-same-mean) came up yesterday, where the OP mentioned that they didn't understand what "assist you with the same" meant — they'd received this in an answer 'in the wild' and didn't understand it.

The question was closed as off-topic, but I'm struggling to understand why. The only two concerns raised in the comments were:

- "I don't see why people wanting to learn actual English as used by native speakers should concern themselves with why "Indian English" favours certain constructions that aren't actually used by mainstream Anglophones"
- "I would never use 'the same' that way. My grandfather might have done, or more likely his father." (Not sure if this was a +1 for closing or just a comment).

In the Help Centre, it says:

> In general, ask here if you have a question which covers:
>
> - **Word choice, usage, and meaning**
> - **Grammar**
> - **Dialect differences**
> - Spelling and punctuation
> - Pronunciation and accents
> - **Other practical problems you encounter or face while learning English**

Arguably, this question covered at least four of those — word choice/grammar, dialect differences and practical problem encountered when learning English.

It's not easily Googleable as searching for "with the same" brings up other styles of usage (e.g. search ignores the final full-stop) and this usage isn't in most mainstream dictionaries that I've checked for "same".

I know that tags aren't 'canon' for what's acceptable or not, but we also have a tag for `indian-english` with 116 questions that says it's for *"for questions related to the English language as spoken and written in India."*

I appreciate the point in the comments, that:

> we shouldn't be encouraging people here to endorse IE usages. This implies no disrespect to either those "English-speaking" Indians themselves OR the "non-mainstream" usages they favour

To me, a better way to solve for this would be to not offer *answers* with words or phrased used in a particular dialect, but to accept *questions* about them. The OP may not have known that the usage was old-fashioned in standard English or particular to Indian English, but to me that points to the need for an answer saying this (which the question already had), rather than needing to be closed.

Comment: That question should be closed because it doesn't have enough context , it has very limited use to other people, and it doesn't explain what the author did to try to answer the question on their own, so we don't understand why the author is having a hard time understanding the phrase. Questions like that attract useless-to-anyone-but-the-author answers. The comments disparaging Indian English are unrelated to the reason I voted to close that question. We don't exclude [questions about AAE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/180962/9161), and we shouldn't exclude questions based on Indian English.

Comment: thanks for the reply @ColleenV — yeah definitely the question could be improved, I  just didn't get the reason it was closed as "Off-topic" specifically rather than say, "Lacking clarity", but guess it's a bit of a moot point. Thanks for the clarification that dialect questions are on-topic

Comment: The post notices suck in terms of letting people understand the reasons why someone voted to close a question. If you click on [the link in the post notice](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions), it lists all of the reasons why something is "off-topic". One person's reasons in the comments for closing the question may not be the sort of reason we would want to encourage, but that doesn't necessarily mean the question shouldn't be closed. It should have never been migrated to ELL in the state it was in. If we accept those migrations, we will get more of them.

Comment: [Please don't migrate obviously off-topic questions to ELL - it just makes things harder on the author](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11075/80039) explains why I personally am a bit harder on migrated questions than questions where we can interact with the author and help them improve their question.

Comment: @ColleenV that makes sense re: migrated questions alright — wasn't thinking about in the context of "this was actively moved on as-is". Cheers for the background thread on it

Comment: One other thing to note, if the post notice says “This question does not appear to be about learning the English language within the scope defined in the help center.” That means there wasn’t enough agreement among the close voters to display a specific reason from the “Community specific” reasons the close voters chose, which is why the notice was so unhelpful for that particular question.